# Tascam US 122 incompatibility with Yosemite

Tags: macos, usb, audio

I've got a Tascam US 122 and it will not work with Yosemite. I've spent months searching for a solution, but there doesn't seem to be one. I can't accept that. Tascam's official line is:

"The US-122 dates back over 12 years now.
As explained, the hardware used by it does not make it possible to operate with current Operating Systems.
It was supported by Mac OSX up to 10.3 and Windows XP 64."

I've read that the problem could stem from the fact that earlier Mac operating systems were 32 bit, and with Yosemite being 64 bit, it won't work. But it will work on 64 bit Windows systems. I've tried every driver that Tascam has available for download in the hope that one *might* just work, but no dice. It ran flawlessly on OS X  10.5.8 for years, despite that being unsupported. 
And yes, I could just upgrade. But I won't. The unit is fine. I know it's still drawing power because the Phantom light still operates. I absolutely refuse to add this to landfill.
So my question is: Is there any way I can 'trick' the Us 122 into thinking it's a compatible unit? I did wonder about trying to give it the firmware upgrade for a compatible unit, but I couldn't find any info about that.
Apologies if I've posted this in the wrong place. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you've just hit that point where it's not going to work on anything newer.

Manufacturers will only keep producing compatible drivers so long as it's reasonably simple for them to keep doing so; for instance if there was a current & an obsolete interface that could both use the same driver set [presumably as internally they'd be using the same base chipset].

I've a drawer full of old audio cards, going back to the 90's... PCI, firewire, you name it - not really sure why I hang onto them any more, except for the fact there's nothing at all wrong with them that a new driver wouldn't fix.

My current Line6 UX2 is probably not long for this world either. It has new drivers for Sierra, but they stopped updating the input amp simulator software a long time ago, so it's only a matter of time.

On the upside, chances are a new system would actually have far better DACs & be lighter on the system, probably lower latency too.
The current replacement for the US-122, the [US-2x2](http://tascam.com/product/us-2x2/) right now has a buy-back offer for your old hardware [though US-only] so it might be worth having a look

Comment: Oh well. I do have a door that I need to prop open with something useless...Thanks for replying.

Comment: You have my sympathy - but I'm afraid that's the way they all go; way of the world, it seems ... as musicians we're used to having guitars that last for decades, but computer components - including my Line6 Variax - become obsolete alarmingly quickly by comparison :(

Answer (score 0):

I can use my US-122 on OS 10.7.5, but have to do the following:

Reboot the Mac, then immediately hold down the 3 & 2 keys to reboot in 32-bit mode.  Totally works!

As for whether it'll work with Sierra, well, that's why I'm currently moseying around support pages...

Good luck!

Comment: Ok I thought this was a troll comment but it's real - https://support.apple.com/en-gb/ht3773.